# Is there a way or a convention to know or indicate the first frames of a GIF?

Tags: support

Sometimes gif animations are hard to understand because we don't know where the sequence begin.

Is there a convention to indicate the beginning (something special to add at the beginning of the sequence) ?

Or is there a way to see it by itself with some option in the browser ?

Comment: It depends on the software you use to create the gifs. In Gifcam there is an option to have certain frames play for a longer time.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion long gifs illusrating complex actions are not very useful for that very reason.

I think it's better to create short pieces in which the beginning and end of the process are evident. Video shoud be a supporting element of what has been explained on the answer, so that users are aware of what to look for. I like short explanations, a gif, more explanation and another gif and so on. Breaking complicated processes into smaller ones.

I'd rather err on the side of oversimplifying/clarifying than making a show out of an anwser.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I have finally found that the *screencast keys* addon has a time option which does the job.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh a page they should start from scratch again, or perhaps open them in a new tab (Right click > View Image.)

Anyway unless you manually add a frame counter or a progress bar to your GIFs (which some software allows) there really isn't a direct way to know.

I some times bother to edit my GIFs to have  have a pause or a longer frame at the beginning or end to make it clearer where it stops, but I don't always do it, and not every user bothers to do so.